# GORM Not ignoring field with `gorm:"-"`

Tags: go, go-gorm

Using Jinzhu's GORM Package which is fantastic btw, I currently have this struct:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    // The Users username
    Username string `gorm:"size:255;unique;not null"`

    // The Users email address
    Email string `gorm:"size:255;unique;not null"`

    // The Users hashed password
    Password string `gorm:"size:255;not null"`

    // The Users password confirmation (only for forms)
    PasswordC string `gorm:"-"`

    // The Users FULL NAME (e.g. Burt Reynolds)
    Fullname string `gorm:"size:255; not null"`

    // The Users Karma level
    Karma int

    // Is the user banned?
    Banned bool
}
```

But I also use Gorilla's `Schema` package so any form values populate the struct, but I don't want the `PasswordC` to be saved into the database because it will be plain text as the normal `Password` field gets bcrypt'd so any information on how to make `GORM` not save the `PasswordC` field.

Comment: The gorm docs indicate that's the correct syntax for ignoring a field: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#model-definition - are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: try to replace it via,     PasswordC string `sql:"-"`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [docs](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#model-definition) say `gorm:"-"`, but the [code](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/021d7b33143de37b743d1cf660974e9c8d3f80ea/model_struct.go#L160) indicates `sql:"-"` is the correct syntax.

My testing verifies this.

Comment: This is no longer correct. The [code](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/commit/465f8ea05b5638e508d29985eed6615402a9c2eb) has been fixed.

Comment: Confirmed. Paweł Koniarski is correct, at least as of today gorm: "-" does not add field to database.

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer correct. The code has been fixed, still use `gorm:"-"`.